# Unity and Oculus Raycast from Motion Controller Only working at Guardian Border

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting, oculus

I have coded up a simple raycast script that is attached to the hand of an Oculus Motion Controller.  The idea is - the controller acts like a vacuum, it sucks up the prefabbed objects called "Eosinophil2(Clone)".

On a few tests outside of the motion controller this works.

The trouble I am experiencing is when I place the Raycast script into the motion controller.  It only appear to work as anticipated when I am beside the Guardian Border.

I have turned on and off the border to see if that solved anything but it did not.

I've checked that the line raycast line goes in the right direction - and it is.

Any ideas?

```
 void FixedUpdate()
{
   // OVRInput.SetControllerVibration(.3f, 0.3f, OVRInput.Controller.RTouch);
    var up = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
    //note the use of var as the type. This is because in c# you 
    // can have lamda functions which open up the use of untyped variables
    //these variables can only live INSIDE a function. 
    RaycastHit hit;
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, up * 20, Color.green,1);


    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, up, out hit, 20))
    {

        if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "Eosinophil2(Clone)")
        {
            OVRInput.SetControllerVibration(.3f, 0.3f, OVRInput.Controller.RTouch);
            hit.collider.gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(hit.collider.gameObject.transform.position, transform.position, 20 * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        else
        {
            //OVRInput.SetControllerVibration(0, 0, OVRInput.Controller.RTouch);
        }
    }
}


private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.transform.name == "Eosinophil2(Clone)")
    {
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play(0);
        Debug.Log("works");
        Destroy(other.gameObject);

        Debug.Log("HIT ONE!");
        hitRate++;
    }
}`enter code here`
```

Comment: I am unsure of what happened.  But I rebuild the scene with a new OVRCamerRig and it all worked as expected.  Admittedly I was using a prebuilt scene from Oculus and I'd imagine there was something in there fighting against my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moral of the story - build your scene from scratch.

Use the OVRCameraRig prefab in said build scene.

Using prebuilt scenes from Oculus can be detrimental to ones health, time and code.

I hope this helps someone someday.